# UIKit Change Presented View Controller's Layout Constraints Relative to Parent View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working on a project in UIKit, *without storyboards* (only programmatic layout constraints) and, following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-preview-files-using-quick-look-and-qlpreviewcontroller), I have a custom view controller like this:

```swift
@objc public class testController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let previewController = QLPreviewController()
        previewController.dataSource = self
        
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    
    public func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String("beans"), withExtension: "pdf") else {
            fatalError("Could not load \(index).pdf")
        }

        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }
     
}
```

Then, in my main View Controller file, I add this testController as a subview like so:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let test = testController()
        self.view.addSubview(test.view)
        test.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
    }


}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to be able to change my testController's programmatic layout constraints *relative to it's parent view*.

I've tried stuff like this in the main view controller (ViewController):

```swift
       let test = testController()
        self.view.addSubview(test.view)
        test.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        test.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 200, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

but this simply doesn't work/the view doesn't reflect these constraints at all and it seems like the only way I can successfully modify the constraints of the testController, is within the `viewDidAppear` function of the testController class.

However, if I try something like this:

```swift
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let previewController = QLPreviewController()
        previewController.dataSource = self

        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true //notice how this works since it's a hardcoded 200
        previewController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true //this throws an error

        present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I get an error thrown.

So I'd somehow like to access the *parent* of testViewController I guess, and use it for the constraints of the view. I've tried unsuccessfully using `presentingViewController` and `parent` for this, but they either return nil or throw an error.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: what's realView?

Comment: sorry was a typo, meant to be `test.view`

Answer (score 1):

This is sample to add view and change the constraints, in your example you have to add more constraint to test view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let buttonTest: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("go to ", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        self.view.addSubview(buttonTest)
        buttonTest.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttonTest.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            buttonTest.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        let secondView = SecondViewController()
        self.view.addSubview(secondView.view)
        secondView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            secondView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant: 100),
            secondView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            secondView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            secondView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100)
        ])
        
        
    }

}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, yes this is just what I'm looking for thank you but it doesn't seem to work for some reason with the QLPreview controller, since I have to manually call the `present` function? Is there a way I can do exactly this, but using the QLPreview controller? so `class SecondViewController: UIViewController,  QLPreviewControllerDataSource{ ... }`

Comment: might need to somehow add the secondviewcontroller as a child of the first? I'll post if I figure it out